# Old Transistor radio troubleshooting

Tags: rf, oscillator, radio

I am repairing an old four band Transistor MW+ SW radio for which a circuit diagram is unavailable. The radio has four RF transistors, four AF transistors and a Germanium detector diode. Suddenly it is unable to receive any stations, neither will it pass a 455 kHz test signal from the external antenna input to the audio stage. It only passes a faint test signal from the base of the second RF transistor to the audio stage, but a  strong one from one terminal of the second IF transformer. However, I am confident that the audio section is working fine as I was able to connect my MP3 player and play it at full volume without distortion.

It was working almost perfectly after replacing old electrolytics and the Ge transistors with new ones and I was even able to measure the IF of 465 kHz at the collector of the last RF transistor. Something went wrong after I tried to fix the intermittent longwave reception. Now the only frequency measurement I get is 1.6 MHz at the collector of the first transistor.

I have a multimeter and signal generator but no oscilloscope.

Are there any tests I can do to help diagnose the fault?

Comment: First run a VBE & VCE measurement campaign throughout the whole RF stages, just to see if any transistor is off. You may also check all IF transformers windings for open circuit, it's a not uncommon sneaky fault

Comment: I bet there is a schematic. What's the radio?

Comment: [Old radio schematics](http://www.nucow.com/120,000FREE.htm) - first hit.

Comment: Carl. Will do and post the results here later today. : The radio's a Loewe Opta Dolly 8 export for which even the Bocket Radio museum could not give me an exact schematic. There were many versions of this radio and none of the diagrams on their website match my model.

Comment: Bob, use [Enter] x 2 for paragraph breaks in markdown syntax.

Comment: Old transistors - and Ge transistors in general - are very sensitive to soldering temperatures. Did you use precautions (holding the pins with a plier to add thermal mass) when soldering the new ones? Maybe you cooked them.

Comment: Yes, it is standard practice for me to use forceps as heatsinks when soldering transistors and diodes.

Comment: Carl. Here are the measurements using a 5.8V supply:

Comment: @carloc. Here are the RF transistor voltage measurements using a 5.8V supply: Transistor 1: vBE 0.04V, vCE 2.44V; Transistor 2: vBE 0.1V, vCE 4.72V; Transistor 3: vBE 0.24V, vCE 4.45V; Transistor 4: vBE 0.25V, vCE 4.04V.

Comment: #1 VBE looks really to small to me.... try have a look around that stage, check the ferrite antenna windings connections too, sometimes bias comes thru them. Also please post "similar" schematics you found, sometimes they are the same to some extend

Comment: Here is a link to the schematics. Apologies for not posting the actual documents, which are copyrighted.http://www.radiomuseum-bocket.de/wiki/index.php?title=Loewe_Opta_Dolly_8_Export

Comment: I am able to pass and measure a 455 kHz RF test signal from the external antenna input socket right to the beginning of the audio stage but only when the radio is powered off. My signal injector has an audio tone, but I cannot hear it nor can I measure it's frequency when the radio is powered on. I can also hear a rushing sound on a nearby radio  when I rotate the tuning capacitor. There are no breaks in the ferrite antenna coils and both IF stages and AF stages are fine. Can a oscillator transistor oscillate at the wrong frequency ? I am measuring around 2 MHz at its collector.

Comment: MW radios use LO above, i.e. 0.54-1.6MHz RF in turns into 1-2.1MHz local oscillator, so what you measured sounds good. Also if you measure LO it alaos means first stage self oscillating mixer is probably ok. It all looks quite rusty, what about a simple poor contatct somewhre?

Comment: @carloc. It did have rust on speaker and chassis and the pushbutton piano switches are not in good condition. I cleaned them with Servisol. So Iam checking every wire and solder points. The radio is 60 years old but sounded nice when it was working. Multiband including shortwave is a great advantage. Much appreciated.

Comment: I love those 60's electronics, hope you fix it.